# variable substitution inside a function symbol in first order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

I don't understand if variable substitution in formula might change a variable appearance  inside a function symbol.

For example, In the formula $\alpha : y=f(x)$. Does $\alpha(y) : y=f(y)$. Is considered to be a "legal" substitution of variable $x$ by $y$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is. This does not mean that the "meaning" of the formula does not change. Consider as $\alpha$ the formula: $y=x+1$; we have that $\alpha[y/x]$ will be: $y=y+1$.

Comment: thanks! Just to make sure, that means that the formula $(x=y) \rightarrow ((f(x)=f(x)) \rightarrow (f(x)=f(y)))$ is a valid use of the axiom $x=y \rightarrow (\alpha  \rightarrow \alpha\langle y\rangle)  $ (when the partial substitution of $x$ is legal cause $x$ is free variable).

Comment: Why not ? If $x=y$, then $f(x)=f(y)$... it makes sense.

Comment: Great thanks again!!! @MauroALLEGRANZA